# Java JKS API: keyStore is empty

Tags: java, jks

I'm trying to get my PKI material using KeyStore API. The content of my keystore is:

[image]

My code is:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
ks.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(this.boConfiguration.getUiPortalAdminKeyStore()),
    this.boConfiguration.getUiPortalAdminKeyPassword().toCharArray()
);

Enumeration<String> aliases = ks.aliases();
while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
    LOG.debug(aliases.nextElement());
}
Key pK = ks.getKey(
    "gestio",
    this.boConfiguration.getUiPortalAdminKeyStorePassword().toCharArray()
);
Key pKey = ks.getKey("gestio", this.boConfiguration.getUiPortalAdminKeyStorePassword().toCharArray());
Certificate[] certs = ks.getCertificateChain("gestio");
Certificate cert = ks.getCertificate("gestio");
```

My problem is that all `ks.get*` returns me `null`. However, keystore is not empty. Also, `getAlias` method returns me an empty enumeration.

Any ideas?

This is the content according keystore explorer:

[image]

Comment: `getAlias` or `aliases`?

Comment: Why is the resource name dynamic?

Comment: It's defined on properties file according its environment.

Comment: `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream` returns null.

Comment: Why does it return `null`? The value of the property is "classpath:ks.jks", and file is under `src/main/resources`...

Comment: But where is it in the JAR file? Or WAR file? And what is the package name of this class? Those need to agree for this code to work.

Comment: _The value of the property is "classpath:ks.jks"_: Try `"/ks.jks"` as the property value.